# Weird image rendering issue when reading PDF in Microsoft Edge

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

I am trying to read a PDF with some images in it. Here is how it looks in Google Chrome:

[image]

Reading the same pdf in edge looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I would have just used Chrome to read the pdf but I use the advanced pdf annotation features in Edge and would like to continue to use Edge if possible.

Comment: Please share the pdf itself for analysis.

Comment: This is publication paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0968090X16000462) and unfortunately I don't think I am allowed to share it. I have never had this issue with Edge before so I am not sure what is going on and so thought that I would ask here.

Comment: I had find that in a past, some issues occurred with the creators update. If you are using any older updates then try to check for the latest updates and install it. I made a test with Edge 42.17134.1.0 version. I tested more then 15 PDF files loaded with images. All are displaying fine.

Comment: @deepak-msft Version of Edge currently using: `44.17763.1.0`. I have temporarily loaded the file [here](https://akshaygaur.org/How%20to%20assess%20benefits%20of%20connected%20vehicles.pdf) in case this helps in figuring this problem out.

Comment: @mkl please see my comments above for the link to the pdf file.

Comment: That link requires some kind of login. Ah, I see there's another link. I'll try that later in office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In short

This artifact is caused by a weirdness in the PDF itself! It draws a fairly *wide line* with *zero length* over the top left corner of the image. This causes different viewers to create different outputs, Adobe Reader draws nothing, Chrome draws a line, Edge draws a circle.

> Does anybody know how to fix this?

Remove this nonsensical operation from the PDF.

#### In detail

This is an excerpt of the operations in the content stream of the page at hand, comments (the '%' lines) added by me:

```
% Fill the bottom section of the page with white color
1 1 1 rg
36.85 54.425 466.242 204.831 re
f
% Show the bitmap image
q
226.885 0 0 189.694 155.905 69.562 cm
/Im4 Do
Q
% Start a marked content block
/Figure <</MCID 0>>BDC
q
1 i 
% Create a clip path along the image borders
% (to make following operations only operate on the image)
155.905 259.257 m
382.79 259.257 l
382.79 69.562 l
155.905 69.562 l
W n
q
% Set a number of properties to eventually draw a line with 0 length
% and ca. 200 width over the top left corner of the image
1.0936 0 0 -.91438 0 0 cm
0 0 0 RG
0 J 0 j 207.458 w 10 M []0 d
q 1 0 0 1 142.556 -283.534 cm 0 0 m
0 0 l
s
Q
EMC
Q
Q
```

Thus, there indeed are PDF content instructions for drawing something onto the top left corner of the image. Unfortunately, though, these instructions are difficult to follow:

To properly draw a line of a given width, one needs to know the direction of the line. But the line length here is 0, so there is no recognizable direction of the line nor is there the orthogonal direction in which to apply the width.

An obvious choice is to draw nothing at all. But 0 length may also be interpreted to mean "as short as possible while still visible", in particular as there is an explicit requirement to that effect for a 0 *width* line in the PDF specification.

As a result different viewers draw different results,

- Adobe Reader draws nothing,

  [image: Adobe Reader screen shot]
- Chrome considers the 0 length line to be horizontal (an arbitrary choice) and draws a very short, very wide horizontal line,

  [image: Chrome screen shot]
- Edge does not choose an arbitrary direction but instead applies the width in all directions, resulting in a circle.

  [image: Edge screen shot]

As soon as the instructions drawing that line are removed, all viewers show the identical image as surely intended.

Comment: Thanks! Lol at the `nonsensical operation` bit. This seems to be the correct answer. Since I don't have the source of the pdf, I won't be able to remove the weird line drawing instruction though.

Comment: *"Since I don't have the source of the pdf, I won't be able to remove the weird line drawing instruction though."* - Well, you can. E.g. I uncompressed the PDF streams using qpdf and then, using a hex editor, overwrote the `0 0 m 0 0 l s` with space characters. The result PDF does display the image in question without issue.

Comment: I didn’t know you could do that! I will try it out tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I again try to make a test with your PDF file.

I am able to produce the issue with the Edge.

[image]

I think there is some issue with the format of Image.

For testing purpose, I download the file and open in MS Word then save it as PDF again.

Then I open it in MS Edge and it shows image correctly.

So at present, You can try to use this work around to avoid the issue.

I will try to inform the developers team about this issue. It may take some time to get response from them.

until then you can try to use the work around steps.

[image]

Comment: *I think there is some issue with the format of Image.* - No, there indeed are vector graphics instructions drawing something over the image, cf. my answer. The bitmap image itself does not have any problems.

Comment: I think @mkl answer makes more sense with respect to source of the problem. However, since I don't have the source of the pdf, I am using your method as a workaround. I hope that developers of Edge replicate the functionality of Adobe Reader in cases like these, but since this is probably a rare scenario, I will not hold my breath over it.